# Заполнение таблицы javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

В FXML сделал таблицу со столбиками, пытаюсь заполнить ее в контроллере

```
@FXML
public TableView<ObservableList<Students>> table;

@FXML
public TableColumn<Students, String> id_column;

@FXML
public TableColumn<Students, String> name_column;

@FXML
public TableColumn<Students, String> count_column;
...
```

Метод FillTable должен по идее заполнять таблицу входящими значениями, вот код:

```
  @FXML
void initialize() {
System.out.println(table);
//выведет сслыку на table
    columnSettings();
    help.setOnAction(event -> {
        SendCommand.help();
    });
    info.setOnAction(event -> {
        SendCommand.info();
    });
    show.setOnAction(event -> {
        SendCommand.show();
    });
}
public void FillTable(String[] string){
System.out.println(table);
//выведет null
    table.getItems().add((getStudents(string)));
}

public static ObservableList<Students> getStudents(String[] str){
    ObservableList<Students> students= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    students.add(new Students(str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5],str[6],str[7],
            str[8],str[9],str[10],str[11]));
    return students;
}
public void columnSettings(){
    id_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    name_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    count_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("count"));
    exp_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("exp"));
    form_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("form"));
    semester_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("semester"));
    admin_name_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("admin_name"));
    height_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("height"));
    weight_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weight"));
    eye_color_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("eye_color"));
    x_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("x"));
    y_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("y"));
}
```

Вызываю columnSettings до FillTable, но таблица не заполняется, sout(table) выводит null, может кто-то подсказать в чем ошибка?

P.S класс Students:

```
public class Students {
 String id;
 String name;
 String count;
 String exp;
 String form;
 String semester;
 String admin_name;
 String height;
 String weight;
 String eyeColor;
 String x;
 String y;

public Students(String id, String name, String count, String exp, String form, String semester, String admin_name, String height, String weight, String eyeColor, String x, String y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.form = form;
    this.semester = semester;
    this.admin_name = admin_name;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public String getAdmin_name() {
    return admin_name;
}

public String getExp() {
    return exp;
}

public String getEyeColor() {
    return eyeColor;
}

public String getForm() {
    return form;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public String getSemester() {
    return semester;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public String getX() {
    return x;
}

public String getY() {
    return y;
}
}
```

**UPD**

Вызов FillTable:

```
answer.list.stream().forEach((str)->{
            String[] stringArray;
            System.out.println(str);
            stringArray=str.split(",");
            WorkController workController=new WorkController();
            workController.FillTable(stringArray);
        });
```

Видимо проблема в том, что table не возвращает ссылку на объект, в initialize все ок, а как ее получить из FillTable?

Comment: Метод `table.getItems().add()` вроде бы добавляет только один элемент (нужно добавить весь список, который вернул метод getStudents, каждый элемент списка - как отдельная строка, а у вас этот список добавляется как одна строка таблице). Попробуйте `addAll` вместо `add`. Еще добавление элементов в объект `Students` подозрительно выглядит, добавьте описание этого класса в вопрос.

Comment: @insolor, addAll не дал результата, описание класса добавил

Comment: Я думаю стоит добавить целиком главный класс и контроллер, потому что сейчас не понятно как вы вызываете методы заполнения таблицы.

Comment: @insolor, целиком главный класс закинуть не получиться, слишком громоздкий, дополнил описание initialize() и указал вызов FillTable

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что если вызывать FillTable вне контроллера, то java не видит путь до требуемой таблицы. Пришлось передавать таблицу в качестве аргумента.